# MUC implemention on ejabberd server using xmppFramework

Tags: ios, objective-c, ejabberd, xmppframework, multiuserchat

I want to know that is it possible to create a chatroom and invite people ? I have setup ejabberd on my mac and implemented chat with single buddy following
[this link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup/) but i want to implement MUC. I tried demo project of MUC which come with  xmppframework available [here](https://github.com/sesharim/ios-jabber-client/tree/master/XMPPFramework) ,but every time i get error 404 remote server not found. The delegate method

```
- (void)xmppRoomDidCreate:(XMPPRoom *)sender;
```

never gets called.
Instead

```
- (void)handleDidLeaveRoom:(XMPPRoom *)room
```

this method gets called. Has anyone successfully implemented MUC using localhost as server?If yes then please let me know the XMPP client you are using , because for ejabberd,it says remote server not found.

Comment: please post your solution here @vishal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try with conference.host (presumably conference.localhost) as MUC host ?

Comment: when i set conference.localhost,even - (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender doesnt get called. without using conference this is rthe sequence of methods getting called 1- - (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender  2- - (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender and then i get this in my console

Comment: 2013-01-28 17:09:38:938 MUCTesting[14788:2403] SEND: <presence to="test room/quack"><x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"/></presence>
2013-01-28 17:09:38:987 MUCTesting[14788:1c03] RECV: <presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="test room/quack" to="infoshore@vishal.local/42105216971359373176215881" type="error"><x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"/><error code="404" type="cancel"><remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></presence>

Comment: i finally got it working, i had to put that conference prefix in the name of room..:)...your answer helped ..Thanx..